# Simulating an attachment in the emailtask

Tags: windows-phone-7

In phone7 development, being able to send an email requires the use of the email task. This object doesn't not have an attachments property, and many ppl on various forums have complained about this particular lack of functionality. The problem is that Microsoft applications such as the picture gallery and OneNote have the ability to attach images and sound recordings to emails. This implies that there is a way to attach them.

Question: Is there a "hack" or other method that can be used to send emails with attachments in phone7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to send attachments via the `EmailComposeTask` in a third party app. If you don't want to use an `EmailComposeTask`, you could create a server that runs a webservice which performs the sending of the email. Your app could then upload the attachment to that webservice.